# How to pass user input from view to a class in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I imagine this must be pretty basic, but all my search results only show how to pass data the other way ( model to controller, controller to view, and then view back to controller, but nothing from controller back to model(class).  I am trying to pass user input for a search parameter into the query string for an API.  In the view:

```
<form method="post" action="~/Models/Search">
<input name="artist" placeholder="Enter artist's name" />
```

```
@{Search temp = new Search();
if (Request.Form["artist"] != null)                         //this method doesn't work; trying to get user response and pass it back to search class;
{ temp.Artist = Request.Form["artist"].ToLower(); }         //have to  hardcode search parameter at this time
}
<!--<button>Click Me</button>-->

<script>
var weather = Object();
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
       // var artist = $("#artist").val();

        $.get("@Url.Action("SearchArtist", "Home")", function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            artistInfo = ko.mapping.fromJS(response); //populate the artist search object
            ko.applyBindings(artistInfo);
   });
});
```

});

The class:

```
public class Search
{
    string artist;
    public string Artist { get; set;}
    public Object getArtistInfo()
    {
        string appID = "*************** ";
        artist = "metallica";
        string url = "http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/search?api_key="+ appID + "&format=json&name=" + artist + "&results=1&bucket=genre&bucket=songs";
        //synchronous client;
        var client = new WebClient();
        var content = client.DownloadString(url);
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var jsonContent = serializer.Deserialize<Object>(content);
        return jsonContent;
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
public ActionResult ArtistInfo()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public JsonResult SearchArtist()
    {
        Search artist = new Search();
        return Json(artist.getArtistInfo(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Comment: Your `SearchArtist` method needs a parameter `Search model` and then you need to pass the value to the method - `$.get('@Url.Action("SearchArtist", "Home")', { artist: $('#artist').val() }, function (response) {`

Comment: I'm  sorry, but I don't see how adding a parameter of Search model to my SearchArtist method would help, what is that parameter supposed to be?And how would I pass it that parameter?  How does that get data back to the Search class?

Comment: Did you try it! The second parameter of `.get()` passes the `name/value` pair to the controller method. That method now has a parameter `public JsonResult SearchArtist(Search model)` and the model has a property named `Artist` so the `DefaultModelBinder` with now initialize an instance of `Search` and set the value of the `Artist` property to whatever you typed into the textbox.

Comment: And sorry to be harsh, but your code is awful. A model should never contain a method such as that - that should be in a separate service, and your serializing the object twice (one in the method, and again when you use `return Json()` meaning you have to undo one in the client before it can be used.

Comment: And I have just noticed your textbox does not even have an `id="artist"` which it needs.

Comment: 1.  Excuse me for wanting to understand what some code is intended to do and learn something rather than just randomly typing things in. 2. It doesn't work anyways.  3. I did at least know enough to change name to id.  4.  The code you're so critical of was written by my instructor.  I'll be sure to tell her how awful it is.

Comment: Of course it works. And you need to get a new instructor.

Comment: And here is a [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EE2lqd) to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add attributes (runat="server" and id="chooseyourid") to html forms results below :

if you want to access to values in your code behinde you just need to write the id of your element like below :

/*artiste.value;*/

Comment: The question is tagged `asp.net-mvc` - not web forms!